# Why does a cross-domain angularjs $http.post request fail when a XMLHttpRequest succeeds?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to exercise the Trello API with an application key and token from an angular (version 1.0.5) webapp. The server seems correctly configured to handle [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). A test request with http://test-cors.org from [enable cors](http://enable-cors.org/) works as expected.

When I do a post request in one of my angular controllers:

```
$http.post(url).success(function(data) {
  $scope.server_resp = data;
});
```

I get a *Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers* error. (Even though, as you see below, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to '*'). Why is this header added and can it be removed?

### XMLHttpRequest

When I make the same request using raw XMLHttpRequest, it succeeds. Here are the headers for the XMLHttpRequest:

```
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Host:api.trello.com
Origin:http://192.168.0.125:9000
Referer:http://192.168.0.125:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22

Response
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
Content-Length:563
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Mon, 18 Mar 2013 02:49:37 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00
X-Powered-By:Express
X-Server-Time:1363574977568
```

### Angular $http.post

Here are the headers for the angular initiated request. Note that the browser made a pre-flight OPTIONS request:

```
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK

Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, origin, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:api.trello.com
Origin:http://192.168.0.125:9000
Referer:http://192.168.0.125:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22

Response
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 18 Mar 2013 02:51:00 GMT
X-Powered-By:Express
```

Is there a way to configure angular's request headers to allow the above $http.post() code to work?

Comment: That is because the response is coming from another domain and they have their own rules in serving requests from other domains.

Comment: You can try `$http.jsonp()` to get response from another domain

Comment: @Abilash As I want to do a post, jsonp is not an option (which I recall is only for get requests).

Comment: I'm not as familiar with CORS as I'd like, but I notice your (preflight?) Angular response defines allowable Content-Types: "text/html; charset=utf-8". Your XHR response returns Content-Type: "application/json". It sounds to me like the issue isn't CORS, but a data-type mismatch.

Comment: David, did you found a solution for this? I am still looking an answer for this issue :(

Comment: @Pnct, I finally created a proxy on my server to overcome this. Have you tried Flokagale's answer of deleting Content-type? (I had fiddled with that without precise conclusons)

Comment: Yes, still not working. What's the solution with proxy?

Answer (score 8):

The 'content-type' header is not accepted by the server and is added by default for Angular $http POST request (see [$http doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)). You can try to remove it from your $http config. Inject $httpProvider in your controller, then this might work:

```
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-type']
```

You might have to try with 'content-type' also, I'm not sure of the case to use.

Answer (score 7):

Add the headers param to the $http and you'll be fine.

```
          var config = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'your url',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': undefined
           },
           data: {
              "channel": "#fun-and-game",
              "username": $scope.question.title,
              "text": $scope.question.text,
              "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"
          },
       };

      $http(config).success(function(data) {
         $scope.server_resp = data;
      }).error(function(response) {

      });
```

for more info, check [angularjs $http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: thanks @Olatunde Garuba. Its solved my problem too after attempts too many methods.

Comment: Works for me, too.

Answer (score 1):

As per this angular [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1454), CORS can be made to work by deleting X-Requested-With which causes a pre-flight OPTIONS request:

```
App.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
}
```

Note that I have not tried this personally, but a co-worker had to deltete the header to make his CORS request work.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue and the problem was that I was getting the url wrong.  I was posting to 1/cards/actions/createCard because I missread the docs.  I got an access-control related error even though headers etc. look right.   Posting to 1/cards created a card, which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$http({
      method  : "POST",
      url     : url,
      data    : $.param({key: 'value', key2 : 'value'}),
      headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this issue, create a function in the server side to catch the 'OPTIONS' and just return true. Some thing as follows.

```
    /**
     * @url OPTIONS /
     */
    public function options()
    {
        return;
    }
```