# 404 error when I pass session ID in Post request from angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cross-domain

My services are hosted on remote server and i am consuming services in local angular js app. It works fine in REST request which does not require SessionID in header. When I add Session ID in header it does not work. Gives me 404 error.

app.factory('Dashboard', function($resource, $http) {

```
return {
GetDashboardData : function(sessionid, id) {
alert(sessionid + '\n' + id);
var config = {
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'SessionID': sessionid
}
};

return $http.post('url goes here'+id,config);

}
}
});
```

Comment: I fixed this problem because it was because of cross domain issue, I have made changes to REST API call and it works now.

Comment: you can find solution at following link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490256/why-does-a-cross-domain-angularjs-http-post-request-fail-when-a-xmlhttprequest
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343316/angularjs-and-cross-domain-post

Comment: Thanks Umair for useful links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of  cross domain issue in your rest api call. You should made changes to REST Api call and it will work fine. You are getting 404 because session id is not being accepted on server side.